# Search Refinement Webpart not showing

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, script-webpart

I have 2 questions. Pardon me if i am supposed to post one question at a time.

- I am trying to add `Search Box`, `Search Refinement` and `Search
  Results` web parts to my sharepoint online page. Issue is i can't
  find Search Category in my `Add Web Part`, But I can see `Search
  Driven Content` Category. Also How can i redirect all my searches to
  this newly created page?(I am able to do this all in my own
  sharepoint site but facing issue at client's platform)
- I have a communication site, but cant find Script Editor webpart.

Please let me know how i can solve these issues.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to get the admins to change the "allow custom script" setting. When this setting is off, it blocks a variety of features including the script editor part, as well as search web parts and many other features. The docs that have instructions for changing the setting, as well as the full list of features affected, is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script).

Comment: I got admin access and search webparts are available now, but content/script webpart is still not there

Answer (score 1):

To allow custom script on a particular site collection immediately, run the following PowerShell with SharePoint Online Management Shell:

```
Connect-SPOService

Type: https://<yourdomain>-admin.sharepoint.com

Sign in with username and password

Set-SPOSite -Identity https://<yourdomain>.sharepoint.com -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
```

Comment: already did that